# Getting db values of different rows in single row C# and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
namespace Student.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FStudentID { get; set; }
        public string FStudentName { get; set; }
        public string FSubject { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FMarks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (studentdbentities dbmodel = new studentdbentities())
    {
        //var lis=dbmodel.Students.ToList().Select(x=> x.FStudentName 
        return View(dbmodel.Students.ToList());
    }
}
```

Output should be

```
Name    m1  m2  m3 
--------------------------
abhi    58  38  59  79  90
sakthi  50  35  54  78  90
```

Db part

```
Sid Sname Sub  marks
--------------------
1    m   m1    34
2    m   m2    45
```

I am getting all the values 5 times i need to get it single time, what should i change controller query or view part. It outputs abhi 5 times and sakthi 5 times. What should i do now to get the expected output

Comment: Welcome. Can you give a complete code example to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: Please edit your question and make sure to look at the "preview" box before posting (your question looks quite messy right now). Also please add the code for your view (we can see model and controller but view is missing